# AWS Grant DBA MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, roles, database-administration, sql-grant

Hey I'm trying to grant my USER in mySQL the DBA role, because we are connecting to a AWS amazon server but no matter what we do, we can't grant that role to our user admin5 that's in the only user that we created. So please help because we need that privilege to  create a Job that sends emails automatically at midnight.

Comment: it's a big confusing. admin5 is your MySQL user, or AWS user, or is it a Unix account? And are you getting a mysql error? Also, why do you need to have a DBA account to get data to send an email? That means you're hard coding your DBA account credentials in a batch file, which is pretty bad security. Wouldn't you create an account with only the privileges it needs, and use that instead? We use MySQLWorkbench, and you can grant accesses against RDS using it. I'm assuming you're using RDS?

Comment: RDS has a number of restrictions as to which permissions can be granted.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can [grant privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) to other users:

> `WITH GRANT OPTION` clause gives the user the ability to give to other users any privileges the user has at the specified privilege level.

You can check if your user has this option by running `show grants for 'youruser'@'yourhost';`

The root user usually has these privileges by default. Try logging in with root and granting the permissions you need.

Also, presumably your cron that you are going to be running does not need to have DBA permissions.  Here is a list of [Mysql permissions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) and what they do.  Select and execute privileges would probably be sufficient enough for what you need.

Comment: "DBA role" is some of the typical "helpful" nonsense from MySQL Workbench. You can't have `SUPER` with RDS, which rules out that "role" (which isn't even a MySQL concept - I have no idea what Oracle is thinking, tacking on such bloat). +1 for the correct, native approach.